# How to interpolate in Pandas using only the above/lag values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID   Value
1     5
1     6
1     Nan
2     Nan
2     8
2     4
2     nan
2     10
3     nan
```

Expected output:

```
ID   Value
1     5
1     6
1     7
2     Nan
2     8
2     4
2     2
2     10
3     nan
```

I want to do something like this:

`df.groupby('ID')['Value'].shift(all).interpolate()`

Currently, I am using this code, but it also takes the below rows into account.

`df.groupby('ID')['Value'].interpolate()`

Comment: could u explain the logic a bit more? the third row has a value of 7, the next row is null, the next null is replaced by 2 and the last null stays null. do explain the logic more and you will get some response

Comment: Because the ID is different in 4th row.

Comment: I want to interpolate for each ID. That's why, as you can see the groupby command used.